# Overview of dependencies of npm packages which are used in angular-projects

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, dependency-management

In my company we got some angular projects, and an artifactory with npm packages. The angular projects, are built for Single Page Applications and the npm are dependencies to it.

Since the npm packages changes, we need something like a dependency tree which shows which npm packages is linked to the angular project. Because we need to rebuilt the whole thing if it is a breaking change.

I saw in the artifactory npm registry, there is something like a "dependend to", but I don't know if this is the right way. I don't wanna scan manually every Package Json of every angular project we got.

TLDR:  I want to know which Angular project(s) is using a defined npm package when this package introduce breaking change.

Comment: For clarification, you want to know which Angular project(s) is using a defined npm package when this package introduce breaking change, right ?

Comment: Yeah that's the requirement.

Comment: But how will you trigger this check ? Wouldn't it be easier to have nightly build which update the dependencies, build and execute tests of each projects.

Comment: The thing is we got no such thing as continuous delivery. I would rather say it's a "burocratic delivery".  We got some external contractors which got some build-pipelines, where they can deliver it to test by filling out some complicated "delivery-note" (which will be discussed in meetings before) . This complicated structure includes a lot reconciliation with the contractor. If the npm package changes I need information which angular project got this library included.